# NoClassDefFoundError for androidx.test.espresso.IdlingResource in release build only

Tags: java, android-espresso, release

I've been able to implement the IdlingResource in my espresso tests, but it fails to run on a release build.  Runs just fine on debug build or without IdlingResource, but I really need IdlingResource to manage the timing issues in espresso tests.  I'd much rather submit release builds to Firebase Test Lab as I've done in the past, but seem to have run into a wall with this.

The log shows the faiure as:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.espresso.IdlingResource"

Anyone know how to remedy this problem?

My dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' //:21.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.4.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.firebase:testlab-instr-lib:0.2'

    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
}
```

The error displayed in the run log is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate test runner class androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner

at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.throwInitializationError(AndroidJUnit4.java:129)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:121)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:82)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.<init>(AndroidJUnit4.java:56)
... 15 trimmed
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:112)
... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx.test.espresso.IdlingResource
at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:55)
at java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(Class.java:479)
at java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod.getDexCacheType(ArtMethod.java:229)
at java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod.getReturnType(ArtMethod.java:178)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.getReturnType(Method.java:184)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:771)
at org.junit.internal.MethodSorter.getDeclaredMethods(MethodSorter.java:54)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:65)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.java:43)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.espresso.IdlingResource" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.myco.myapp.test-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myco.myapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:53)
... 34 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.test.espresso.IdlingResource
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

After limiting the androidTest to just a single module and limited functionality, here's the source and the result that's still failing:

```
package myco.myapp

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewParent;

import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.RuleChain;
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario;
import androidx.test.espresso.UiController;
import androidx.test.espresso.ViewAction;
import androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction;
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers;
import androidx.test.filters.MediumTest;
import androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule;
//import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isRoot;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withClassName;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

import androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule;
import androidx.test.espresso.IdlingRegistry;
import androidx.test.espresso.IdlingResource;


@MediumTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
//@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class FullTest
{
    protected IdlingResource mIdlingResource;


    //    @Rule public
    private final GrantPermissionRule mGrantPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    );

    @Before
    public void registerIdlingResource() {
        ActivityScenario activityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity.class);
        activityScenario.onActivity(new ActivityScenario.ActivityAction<MainActivity>() {
            @Override
            public void perform(MainActivity activity) {
                mIdlingResource = activity.getIdlingResource();
                // To prove that the test fails, omit this call:
                IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(mIdlingResource);
            }
        });
    }

    @After
    public void unregisterIdlingResource() {
        new ScreenshotWatcher().quickCapture("EndFullTest");
        if (mIdlingResource != null) {
            IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(mIdlingResource);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void fullTest()
    {
        ViewInteraction relativeLayout = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.menuButton),
                        childAtPosition(
                                childAtPosition(
                                        withClassName(is("com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView")),
                                        1),
                                1),
                        isDisplayed()));
        relativeLayout.perform(click());

        onView(isRoot()).perform(waitFor(1000));

        ViewInteraction relativeLayout2 = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.menuButton),
                        childAtPosition(
                                childAtPosition(
                                        withClassName(is("com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView")),
                                        1),
                                0),
                        isDisplayed()));
        relativeLayout2.perform(click());
    }

    public static Activity getActivity(Context context)
    {
        while (context instanceof ContextWrapper)
        {
            if (context instanceof Activity)
            {
                return (Activity) context;
            }
            context = ((ContextWrapper) context).getBaseContext();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // only included to debug release build issue with IdlingResource
    private static Matcher<View> childAtPosition(
            final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int position)
    {

        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>()
        {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description)
            {
                description.appendText("Child at position " + position + " in parent ");
                parentMatcher.describeTo(description);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view)
            {
                ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
                return parent instanceof ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                        && view.equals(((ViewGroup) parent).getChildAt(position));
            }
        };
    }

    private static ViewAction waitFor(long delay) {
        return new ViewAction() {
            @Override public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
                return ViewMatchers.isRoot();
            }

            @Override public String getDescription() {
                return "wait for " + delay + "milliseconds";
            }

            @Override public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
                uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(delay);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And the resulting log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate test runner class androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner


    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.throwInitializationError(AndroidJUnit4.java:129)
    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:121)
    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:82)
    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.<init>(AndroidJUnit4.java:56)
    ... 15 trimmed
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:112)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/espresso/IdlingResource;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Native Method)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getSortedDeclaredFields(TestClass.java:77)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.java:43)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.espresso.IdlingResource" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.myco.myapp.test-MVOZuSB1ACpe3NJPPu-DeQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myco.myapp-ecz6-CiigbD0vfPUbcjPpA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myco.myapp.test-MVOZuSB1ACpe3NJPPu-DeQ==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.myco.myapp-ecz6-CiigbD0vfPUbcjPpA==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /system/product/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Do you have multiple modules in your project? Maybe one of them is missing it as a release dependency?

Comment: Thanks, Oliver, for your feedback.  Yes, I have one main test entrypoint module with several sub-class modules that do the real work of the test.  I don't set up release vs. debug dependencies - they both use the same set.   With your question in mind, I gutted the main test entrypoint module to do a minimal amount of work by itself so the other modules aren't involved and it still has the same result.  What else would help to facilitate this conversation?